# How to transfer data to another page

Tags: asp.net

Hai, I have an ASP.NET page with 150 controls and i want to transfer data of these controls to another ASP.NET page. what method would be best for this task? Number of controls may increase.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways:

1. Using a Query String  (*Might not work in your case, only good for transferring small amount of data*)
2. Getting Post Information from the Source Page
3. Using Session State
4. Getting Public Property Values from the Source Page
5. Getting Control Information from the Source Page in the Same Application

Its always preferable to wrap the data you want to transfer in an object and pass it using pt. 3 or Pt. 4 , though in case you have arbitrary number of controls, Pt. 5 may work better for you.

This should cover it comprehensively:

- [MSDN: How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)
- [ASP.NET 2.0 : Accessing controls in Previous Page](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37633.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use datatable , populate the contents in the row and send it using session

Another way is use generic class and transfer it using session.

You can also transfer it using below mentioned code

```
TextBox previouspagetextbox = (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("currentpagetextbox");
```

the above mentioned code will be written in the another page where you will access the controls of previous page.

Multiviews is an another option. So you donot need to transfer the contents. It will facilitate you in  same page.

Comment: this is the right solution and I am thinking of that as well.

Comment: i think multiviews option is much better although it'll make a page bit heavier but better than other options

Answer (score 1):

As i could understand your need it will be possible through server side session or any other servers side storing mechanism like you can store the data in the database also and then fetch the control values on the next page by the Primary key or any other composite unique combination but at the cost of your page performance i will suggest you better to use ASP:Wizard control that is available from asp.net 2.0.
Most of the things will be taken care by the asp:wizard and it will be easy for the user of the page to fill up the information in the controls.

for details ion wizard control read on the following **[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163894.aspx)**

Hope it will be helpful.
Happy coding.

Comment: Definitely, sending the 150 control contents and again read from database will be very costly

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Server.Transfer('NewPage.aspx', True)` to redirect to a new page and that page will have access to all of the controls that were on the previous page.
[MSDN Article about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caxa892w.aspx)