# How to transfer data from one page to another page in asp.net, I dont want to use sessions

Tags: asp.net

**How to transfer data from one page to another page in asp.net, I don't
want to use sessions **

Comment: You can use query string..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transfer data to another page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987469/how-to-transfer-data-to-another-page)

Comment: No its not i think as i wanna ask is there any other alternet options as query string is not that much safe to use. Also if user clears the Cookies then to its a big problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Query String & Cookies

**Example for Query String :**

Passing value..

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
// Value sent using HttpResponse
Response.Redirect("Form1.aspx?Name="+txtName.Text);
}
```

Getting value using Query String..

```
 if (Request.QueryString["Name"]!= null) // null checking
 lbl_Name.Text = Request.QueryString["Name"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt action, But can u suggest any other alternet options as query string is not that much safe to use. Also if user clears the Cookies then to its a big problem.

Comment: Session is more secure , Check this reference http://www.itorian.com/2012/07/5-ways-to-send-data-between-aspnet-pages.html

Comment: I heard that sessions make page more heavy, Is that true? Else please correct me